# How can I extract text from PDF files using PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I know there are a lot of PDF extraction methods/techniques, but I'm after a reliable text extractor for PDFs in PHP. All I want is to extract words, but not numbers and no special characters.

Any ideas of solid techniques to achieve this?

Comment: Success greatly depends on the particular PDF document.  Words can be embedded in images within the PDF, or can be assembled from components held in separate parts of the document.  Can you point to a representative example?

Comment: I do not want text from images, all I want is the text that is selectable within a PDF document, simple idea, but is there any concrete pre-made solutions? If not, what would be the steps to create such a script to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zend Framework provides [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html), a php class that will load and parse pdf documents.

[Here is a script](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/zend-lucene-and-pdf-documents-part-2-pdf-data-extraction-437.html) that shows how to extract the text from a loaded Zend_Pdf object.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I know there isnt a stone cold solution, but your answer is the most constructive! Cheers, C

Answer (score 0):

If you use laravel, you can try my library...

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

/*
SYNTAX:
include('class.pdf2text.php');
$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename('test.pdf');
$a->decodePDF();
echo $a->output();
*/

class PDF2Text {
    // Some settings
    var $multibyte = 4; // Use setUnicode(TRUE|FALSE)
    var $convertquotes = ENT_QUOTES; // ENT_COMPAT (double-quotes), ENT_QUOTES (Both), ENT_NOQUOTES (None)
    var $showprogress = false; // TRUE if you have problems with time-out

    // Variables
    var $filename = '';
    var $decodedtext = '';

    function setFilename($filename) {
        $this->decodedtext = '';
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    function output($echo = false) {
        if($echo) echo $this->decodedtext;
        else return $this->decodedtext;
    }

    function setUnicode($input) {
        // 4 for unicode. But 2 should work in most cases just fine
        if($input == true) $this->multibyte = 4;
        else $this->multibyte = 2;
    }

    function decodePDF() {
        // Read the data from pdf file
        $infile = @file_get_contents($this->filename, FILE_BINARY);
        if (empty($infile))
            return "";

        // Get all text data.
        $transformations = array();
        $texts = array();

        // Get the list of all objects.
        preg_match_all("#obj[\n|\r](.*)endobj[\n|\r]#ismU", $infile . "endobj\r", $objects);
        $objects = @$objects[1];

        // Select objects with streams.
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($objects); $i++) {
            $currentObject = $objects[$i];

            // Prevent time-out
            @set_time_limit ();
            if($this->showprogress) {
                flush(); ob_flush();
            }

            // Check if an object includes data stream.
            if (preg_match("#stream[\n|\r](.*)endstream[\n|\r]#ismU", $currentObject . "endstream\r", $stream )) {
                $stream = ltrim($stream[1]);
                // Check object parameters and look for text data.
                $options = $this->getObjectOptions($currentObject);

                if (!(empty($options["Length1"]) && empty($options["Type"]) && empty($options["Subtype"])) )
                    continue;

                unset($options["Length"]);

                // So, we have text data. Decode it.
                $data = $this->getDecodedStream($stream, $options);

                if (strlen($data)) {
                    if (preg_match_all("#BT[\n|\r](.*)ET[\n|\r]#ismU", $data . "ET\r", $textContainers)) {
                        $textContainers = @$textContainers[1];
                        $this->getDirtyTexts($texts, $textContainers);
                    } else
                        $this->getCharTransformations($transformations, $data);
                }
            }
        }

        // Analyze text blocks taking into account character transformations and return results.
        $this->decodedtext = $this->getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations);
    }


    function decodeAsciiHex($input) {
        $output = "";

        $isOdd = true;
        $isComment = false;

        for($i = 0, $codeHigh = -1; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '>'; $i++) {
            $c = $input[$i];

            if($isComment) {
                if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
                    $isComment = false;
                continue;
            }

            switch($c) {
                case '\0': case '\t': case '\r': case '\f': case '\n': case ' ': break;
                case '%':
                    $isComment = true;
                break;

                default:
                    $code = hexdec($c);
                    if($code === 0 && $c != '0')
                        return "";

                    if($isOdd)
                        $codeHigh = $code;
                    else
                        $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16 + $code);

                    $isOdd = !$isOdd;
                break;
            }
        }

        if($input[$i] != '>')
            return "";

        if($isOdd)
            $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16);

        return $output;
    }

    function decodeAscii85($input) {
        $output = "";

        $isComment = false;
        $ords = array();

        for($i = 0, $state = 0; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '~'; $i++) {
            $c = $input[$i];

            if($isComment) {
                if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
                    $isComment = false;
                continue;
            }

            if ($c == '\0' || $c == '\t' || $c == '\r' || $c == '\f' || $c == '\n' || $c == ' ')
                continue;
            if ($c == '%') {
                $isComment = true;
                continue;
            }
            if ($c == 'z' && $state === 0) {
                $output .= str_repeat(chr(0), 4);
                continue;
            }
            if ($c < '!' || $c > 'u')
                return "";

            $code = ord($input[$i]) & 0xff;
            $ords[$state++] = $code - ord('!');

            if ($state == 5) {
                $state = 0;
                for ($sum = 0, $j = 0; $j < 5; $j++)
                    $sum = $sum * 85 + $ords[$j];
                for ($j = 3; $j >= 0; $j--)
                    $output .= chr($sum >> ($j * 8));
            }
        }
        if ($state === 1)
            return "";
        elseif ($state > 1) {
            for ($i = 0, $sum = 0; $i < $state; $i++)
                $sum += ($ords[$i] + ($i == $state - 1)) * pow(85, 4 - $i);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $state - 1; $i++) {
                try {
                    if(false == ($o = chr($sum >> ((3 - $i) * 8)))) {
                        throw new Exception('Error');
                    }
                    $output .= $o;
                } catch (Exception $e) { /*Dont do anything*/ }
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }

    function decodeFlate($data) {
        return @gzuncompress($data);
    }

    function getObjectOptions($object) {
        $options = array();

        if (preg_match("#<<(.*)>>#ismU", $object, $options)) {
            $options = explode("/", $options[1]);
            @array_shift($options);

            $o = array();
            for ($j = 0; $j < @count($options); $j++) {
                $options[$j] = preg_replace("#\s+#", " ", trim($options[$j]));
                if (strpos($options[$j], " ") !== false) {
                    $parts = explode(" ", $options[$j]);
                    $o[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
                } else
                    $o[$options[$j]] = true;
            }
            $options = $o;
            unset($o);
        }

        return $options;
    }

    function getDecodedStream($stream, $options) {
        $data = "";
        if (empty($options["Filter"]))
            $data = $stream;
        else {
            $length = !empty($options["Length"]) ? $options["Length"] : strlen($stream);
            $_stream = substr($stream, 0, $length);

            foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == "ASCIIHexDecode")
                    $_stream = $this->decodeAsciiHex($_stream);
                elseif ($key == "ASCII85Decode")
                    $_stream = $this->decodeAscii85($_stream);
                elseif ($key == "FlateDecode")
                    $_stream = $this->decodeFlate($_stream);
                elseif ($key == "Crypt") { // TO DO
                }
            }
            $data = $_stream;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function getDirtyTexts(&$texts, $textContainers) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($textContainers); $j++) {
            if (preg_match_all("#\[(.*)\]\s*TJ[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
                $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
            elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\(.*\))\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
                $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
            elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\[.*\])\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
                $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
        }

    }

    function getCharTransformations(&$transformations, $stream) {
        preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfchar(.*)endbfchar#ismU", $stream, $chars, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfrange(.*)endbfrange#ismU", $stream, $ranges, PREG_SET_ORDER);

        for ($j = 0; $j < count($chars); $j++) {
            $count = $chars[$j][1];
            $current = explode("\n", trim($chars[$j][2]));
            for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
                if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{2,4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4,512})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map))
                    $transformations[str_pad($map[1], 4, "0")] = $map[2];
            }
        }
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($ranges); $j++) {
            $count = $ranges[$j][1];
            $current = explode("\n", trim($ranges[$j][2]));
            for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
                if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
                    $from = hexdec($map[1]);
                    $to = hexdec($map[2]);
                    $_from = hexdec($map[3]);

                    for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to; $m++, $n++)
                        $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", $_from + $n);
                } elseif (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+\[(.*)\]#ismU", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
                    $from = hexdec($map[1]);
                    $to = hexdec($map[2]);
                    $parts = preg_split("#\s+#", trim($map[3]));

                    for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to && $n < count($parts); $m++, $n++)
                        $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", hexdec($parts[$n]));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations) {
        $document = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($texts); $i++) {
            $isHex = false;
            $isPlain = false;

            $hex = "";
            $plain = "";
            for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($texts[$i]); $j++) {
                $c = $texts[$i][$j];
                switch($c) {
                    case "<":
                        $hex = "";
                        $isHex = true;
                        $isPlain = false;
                    break;
                    case ">":
                        $hexs = str_split($hex, $this->multibyte); // 2 or 4 (UTF8 or ISO)
                        for ($k = 0; $k < count($hexs); $k++) {

                            $chex = str_pad($hexs[$k], 4, "0"); // Add tailing zero
                            if (isset($transformations[$chex]))
                                $chex = $transformations[$chex];
                            $document .= html_entity_decode("&#x".$chex.";");
                        }
                        $isHex = false;
                    break;
                    case "(":
                        $plain = "";
                        $isPlain = true;
                        $isHex = false;
                    break;
                    case ")":
                        $document .= $plain;
                        $isPlain = false;
                    break;
                    case "\\":
                        $c2 = $texts[$i][$j + 1];
                        if (in_array($c2, array("\\", "(", ")"))) $plain .= $c2;
                        elseif ($c2 == "n") $plain .= '\n';
                        elseif ($c2 == "r") $plain .= '\r';
                        elseif ($c2 == "t") $plain .= '\t';
                        elseif ($c2 == "b") $plain .= '\b';
                        elseif ($c2 == "f") $plain .= '\f';
                        elseif ($c2 >= '0' && $c2 <= '9') {
                            $oct = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", substr($texts[$i], $j + 1, 3));
                            $j += strlen($oct) - 1;
                            $plain .= html_entity_decode("&#".octdec($oct).";", $this->convertquotes);
                        }
                        $j++;
                    break;

                    default:
                        if ($isHex)
                            $hex .= $c;
                        elseif ($isPlain)
                            $plain .= $c;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $document .= "\n";
            //$document .= "<br>";
        }

        return $document;
    }
}
```